# vue.js computed property not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Vue JS computed property is not triggered With this markup

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<p>£{{plant_price}}</p>

    <div v-if="selected.plant.variations.length > 0 ">
      <select v-model="selected.plant.selected_variation" class="form-control">
        <!-- inline object literal -->
        <option v-for="(variation, i) in selected.plant.variations" :selected="variation.id == selected.plant.selected_variation ? 'selected' : ''":value="variation.id">
          {{variation.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

---

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: {
    selected: {
      type: {a: '' , b: ''},
      vehicle: '',
      plant: {
      }
    },
  computed: {
plant_price: function() {
  if (this.selected.plant.variations.length > 0 ) {
      var variant = _.find(this.selected.plant.variations, {id: this.selected.plant.selected_variation });
      return variant.price;
  } else {
    return this.selected.plant.price;
  }
}
...
```

`selected.plant` is populated by clicking on a plant - triggering the updateSelected method.

```
<div class="col-sm-4" v-for="(plant, i) in step2.plants">
          <div v-on:click="updateSelected(plant)" ....

 methods: {
      updateSelected: function(plant) {
             this.selected.plant = plant; // selected plant
             if (this.selected.plant.variations.length > 0 ) {
                 this.selected.plant.selected_variation = this.selected.plant.variations[0].id; // set the selected ID to the 1st variation
```

I have checked through the debugger, and can see that all the correct properties are available.

```
selected:Object
    type:Object
    vehicle: "Truck"
    plant:Object
       id:26
       price:"52"
       regular_price:"100"
       selected_variation:421
       variations:Array[2]
          0:Object
              id:420
              name:"small"
              price:52000
              regular_price:52000
          1:Object
               etc...
```

I have a computed property, which should update the `plant_price` based on the value of `selected.plant.selected_variation`.

I grab `selected.plant.selected_variation` and search through the variations to retrieve the price. If no variation exists, then the plant price is given.

I have a method on each product to update the selected plant. Clicking the product populates the selected.plant and triggers the computed plant_price to update the price (as the value of selected.plant.selected_variation has changed).

However, the computed plant_price is not triggered by the select. Selecting a new variant does what its supposed to, it updates selected.plant.selected_variation. Yet my plant_price doesn't seem to be triggered by it.

---

So I refactored my code by un-nesting selected.plant.selected_variation. I now hang it off the data object as

```
data = {
    selected_variation: ''
    }
```

and alter my computer property to reference the data as this.selected_variation. My computed property now works??? This makes no sense to me?

Answer (score 6):

selected.plant.selected_variation isn't reactive and VM doesn't see any changes you make to it, because you set it after the VM is already created.

You can make it reactive with Vue.set()

When your AJAX is finished, call

```
Vue.set(selected, 'plant', {Plant Object})
```

Comment: Thanks @SpeekaDievs, sorry - I didn't explain myself very well... I will update my question

Comment: Your answer was correct to the problem as I described it. I just didn't do a very good job of describing it...

Comment: Where do you put this line of code and could you please explain the arguments? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways you can do it, what you are dealing with is a nested object, so if you want to notify the changes of `selected` to the others you have to use

```
this.$set(this.selected, 'plant', 'AJAX_RESULT')
```

In the snippet I used a `setTimeout` in the `created` method to simulate the Ajax call.

Another way you can do it is instead of making `plant_price` as a `computed` property, you can watch the changes of the nested properties 
 of `selected` in the watcher, and then update `plant_price` in the `handler`, you can check out `plant_price_from_watch` in the snippet.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    plant_price_from_watch: 'not available',
    selected: {
      type: {a: '' , b: ''},
      vehicle: "Truck"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    plant_price() {
      return this.setPlantPrice();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    selected: {
      handler() {
        console.log('changed');
        this.plant_price_from_watch = this.setPlantPrice();
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$set(this.selected, 'plant', {
        id: 26,
        price: '52',
        regular_price: '100',
        selected_variation: 421,
        variations: [
          {
            id: 420,
            name: "small",
            price: 52000,
            regular_price: 52000
          },
          {
            id: 421,
            name: "smallvvsvsfv",
            price: 22000,
            regular_price: 22000
          }
        ]
      })
    }, 3000);
  },
  methods: {
    setPlantPrice() {
      if (!this.selected.plant) {
        return 'not available'
      }
      if (this.selected.plant.variations.length > 0 ) {
          const variant = _.find(this.selected.plant.variations, {id: this.selected.plant.selected_variation });
          return variant.price;
      } else {
        return this.selected.plant.price;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>£{{plant_price}}</p>
  <p>£{{plant_price_from_watch}}</p>
  <div v-if="selected.plant && selected.plant.variations.length > 0 ">
    <select v-model="selected.plant.selected_variation" class="form-control">
      <!-- inline object literal -->
      <option v-for="(variation, i) in selected.plant.variations" :selected="variation.id == selected.plant.selected_variation ? 'selected' : ''":value="variation.id">
        {{variation.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kevlai22 - I'm afraid I have edited my question, as the one I posted was full of errors...  Please see edit to question

Comment: @Rob I don't quite get your `updateSelected` method, what are you passing into as `a`??

Comment: The entire plant object. I have a list of plants that I render out (this list is obtained via ajax). On each plant, I attach an update method. I simply pass the entire plant into the update function as a. This updates the selected plant. I've updated my question for clarity by changing a to plant

Comment: @Rob So there's actually a separate list of plants (let's call it `plantList`) that's retrieved by an ajax call and `updateSelected` will update what to put in `selected.plant`, which will then affect what to choose in the dropdown list??